# Is the JQuery Grails plugin needed at all now that Grails 2.0 is released (with JQuery as the default)?

Tags: jquery, upgrade, grails-2.0

The release notes of Grails 2.0 mention that it has removed Prototype in favour of JQuery as the default.  I am curious if the JQuery plugin is at all needed anymore (if it offers anything on top of Grails' default now) or if it should be removed if upgrading a Grails application from 1.3.7 that uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the plugin is still needed, but is included by default in new Grails 2 projects.  I found this in the generated BuildConfig.groovy.

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
    ...
```

Comment: You're right, it looks like the integration is still done via the plugin, just baked in.